# Do other languages have variables shared between threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, low-level, dataflow

I guess it would be too complex for Node.js / JavaScript to leverage, but I've been working with clusters in node to break big tasks down so all cores can work at once but the inter-process messaging provided by Node seems to stringify the data to JSON and re-parse, causing a high overhead on sharing calculated results between worker and master threads.

It seems like you could let multiple threads all read to / write from the same memory location in RAM if you wanted. Yes, you'd have a problem if two threads tried to write to the same memory location at the same time, but you could do a timeshare, allowing each thread to only read/write the location during certain nanosecond intervals. Is such a thing possible in lower level languages, and if so, is it a common practice? If yes, what's the terminology for it? In not, why?

Comment: If you’re using real threads, they have variables shared between them. It doesn’t have a name because it is the default behavior. JavaScript doesn’t, because it is (always?) single-threaded.

Comment: @Telastyn It [launches a cluster of processes that each operate in their own thread](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Is that different than how usual multi-threading works?

Comment: Processes have separate memory spaces (unless utilizing OS supplied shared memory blocks). Threads within a single process do not (excepting thread-local shenannigans)

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between a process and a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Most languages do allow variable sharing been threads without serialisation. In some languages, you can even share variables between processes using shared memory.

Yes, you're correct that synchronisation is a problem in all languages that supports it. The most common and most basic way to solve the synchronisation issue is using a simple lock, also known as mutual exclusion, or mutex. Before a thread can work using a variable, they need to acquire the lock, and they can release the lock after they're done working with the variable. Other than locks, there are many other synchronisation mechanisms like semaphores, condition variable, event/message queue, etc.

I think a lot of higher level languages have found it much easier and safer to write large concurrent programs with message passing rather than sharing variables, additionally with higher level languages, the language interpreter itself has internal state that can be screwed up if not synchronised between threads, which is why many interpreters that allows shared variables make use of either a global interpreter lock or by disallowing threads completely.

While disallowing shared variables make it easier to write thread safe programs, shared variables do have some advantages, in that it's much more direct and lower level, and so it has the potential to be much faster because they don't have the overhead of message serialisation.

Comment: Rust lets you have your cake and eat it too.  You get shared memory between threads, but without having any kind of runtime _and_ guaranteed safety.

The downside is you have to prove to the compiler that it is safe, by properly constraining what kinds of things are in the shared memory and how they can be accessed.  This can be very difficult for somebody new to the concepts, but is typically worth it, especially in complex programs.  This is in fact exactly the kind of problem which lead to the creation of Rust in the first place.

Comment: @Turksarama yes but in Rust the usual way to prove a shared variable safe is to put a Mutex around it. Sharing read-only data is usually fine though (if it doesn't have interior mutability)

Comment: I bet someone could use Rust or C++ or something to make a Node.js module that lets you link a JavaScript object between threads. I realize there are problems to work around when sharing memory for a variable, but if a developer understands those, I bet there are perfectly valid use-cases for some Node.js servers somewhere using clustering and needing that non-serialized message cross thread information passing speed. Sure, other languages are better at it but theres an argument to be made for letting high level languages access lower level features for development speed purposes